# SQL in vs intersection

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select results from a table

```
USER HOBBY
John Sport
Ann  Piano
Lee  Reading
Ann  Sport
Lee  Piano
```

And I want to search people who have more than one common hobbies. Which query has better performance,

```
select user from table where hobby = "sport"
intersect 
select user from table where hobby = "piano"
```

Or

```
select user from table where user in (select user from table where hobby = "piano") and where hobby = "sport"?
```

Comment: Both MySQL and Oracle tags? Which is it? Both have different optimisers and will create different plans. And will you be on a multi-processor system that can run highly parrallel plans, or a single-processor single core machien that must do everything sequentially?  And even then, have you actually tried them both on sample data that would reflect your real world circumstances?

Comment: MySQL doesn't even support `intersect` anyway

Comment: +1 to Yangrui.... optimization is very specific to the size of the data, the cardinality, the hardware, the software, etc.  Talking about it in general is usually a waste of time.  Benchmark them both and you will know the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I use Oracle. I just thought MySQL and Oracle use the same syntax so I tagged both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, assuming `(USER, HOBBY)` is unique, you could use a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT user
  FROM user_hobby
 WHERE hobby IN ('piano', 'sport')
 GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This will make Oracle perform at most a single pass on data whereas the INTERSECT would treat each query separately and would therefore need two passes.

Comment: this will show you only users having two matching hobbies, not users having "more than one" common hobby ;)

Comment: This is an equivalent of the intersect query. I may have misunderstood the OP's requirements though :)

Answer (score 1):

best performance is from
select user from table where hobby = "sport" or hobby = "piano"

but if this is just a teorical excample, then many test have been made, here some:
http://www.execsql.com/post/intersectexcept-versus-innot-in

BTW there isn't a better solution than try out by yourself the execution time of the query