# What are the sql commands that substitute the INTERSECT to achieve greater performance

Tags: sql

Explain how one can substitute the INTERSECT with other SQL commands to achieve

greater performance.

Comment: If `INTERSECT` is the right tool for the job, and most cleanly expresses what you're trying to do, it's unlikely that there's an alternative formulation that avoids the keyword that will perform better. Use whatever tools your database offers to examine whatever plan is being created for your query and identify e.g. missing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the **UNION** command, **INTERSECT** also operates on two SQL statements. The difference is that, while UNION essentially acts as an OR operator (value is selected if it appears in either the first or the second statement), the **INTERSECT** command acts as an AND operator (value is selected only if it appears in both statements).

For theory, many tests have been made, here some: http://www.execsql.com/post/intersectexcept-versus-innot-in

BTW there isn't a better solution than to try out by yourself and the execution time of the query

References:

- [Ref 1](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/77114-best-alternative-intersect)
- [Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458826/sql-in-vs-intersection)